# NSUrlConnection request fails after hours when calling it continuously

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

My app polls 5 asynchronous request for every 5 seconds. These 5 asynchronous request are local requests like 

request 1 : 192.168.0.1/1, 

request 2 : 192.168.0.1/2 ... upto 5

which returns JSON. After few hours i found  request 1,2 and 3 are failing. but for other 2 requests i am getting success response. I tried using another device and i found all the five apis' are working properly. I checked the app with iOS client tool. I observed delegate "didFailWithError" is called for my request in failure device. 
I killed the app from background and tried it again but it remained same. I finally deleted the app and reinstalled and it worked for me. I found this below line in log which is not found on my succeeded device log.

```
PLClientLogging: record locationd withContent {} can't continue due to nils!
```

Please can anyone tell me whether the above line is the reason for the app to behave like this. what is PLClientLogging means? Is it something related to jail broken?

Comment: Did you log the the error value from `didFailWithError`?

Comment: no. It is from device logs. We can get device logs from Xcode > window > device logs where we get all the logs including system logs. i am requesting for SSID name along with that asynchronous calls every 5 seconds. Is it because of this.